# Longest subsequence in a list of positive numbers having sum at most k

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given an array of positive numbers a[1],a[2],..., a[n], how can I find the length of the longest (not necessarily contiguous) subsequence of numbers, such that their sum is less than or equal to a given number k? I must not change the order of the elements of the array (No Sorting).

I know if we take the brute force approach there are 2^n cases we have to consider. Another simple solution (if there wasn't the constraint) would be to sort the array and keep adding the elements until we reach a sum of k. Can we do better?

Edit:
Time complexity has to be linear with respect to n. Meaning something like O(k*n) would be acceptable. There are no other constraints regarding input size, the range of the numbers, etc. I am looking for a DP solution.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252791/discussion-on-question-by-gerimos-longest-subsequence-having-sum-atmost-k); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach based on Quicksort. The time complexity in the average case is O(n) because unlike Quicksort, we never need to recurse on both sides.

1. Initialise two arrays `A` and `B`.
2. Choose a `pivot` element, and initialise a counter `numPivots = 0`.
3. For each element `x` in the array, either append `x` to `A`, increment `numPivots`, or append `x` to `B`, depending on if `x` is less than, equal to, or greater than `pivot` respectively.
4. Let `a = sum(A)` and `b = a + pivot * numPivots`.
5. If `a > k`, recurse on `(A, k)` and return the result.
6. Otherwise if `b >= k`, return `len(A) + floor((k - a) / pivot)`.
7. Otherwise, recurse on `(B, k - b)` and return the result plus `len(A) + numPivots`.

Since it's recursive, we need a base case, which is trivial - if the array's length is zero, return 0.

The exact analysis will depend on how the pivot is chosen, but is isomorphic to the [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm, which likewise partitions and then recurses on at most one side. This means it's possible to achieve O(n) time even in the worst case using a [median of medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) to choose the pivot, but this may or may not actually be necessary for your use-case.

Comment: Quickselect has O(n^2) worst case complexity.

Comment: @n.m. As I said, that depends on how you choose the pivot. Naive or randomised quickselect has worst case O(n^2) complexity, but if you can choose a good enough pivot then it becomes O(n) worst case. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians): *"If one instead consistently chooses "good" pivots, this is avoided and one always gets linear performance even in the worst case."*

Comment: @n.m. No worries, it was worth clarifying in the answer.

Comment: Changed my answer to worst case `O(n * log(k))` time and `O(1)` space. (cc @n.m.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's worst case `O(n * log(k))` time and `O(1)` space -- binary search the value of the highest number in the optimal solution. This is searchable by binary search because as this number increases so does the number of elements allowed in the candidate sum.

If at the end of the search, there is a number `g` in the list for which we can add all the numbers less than or equal to it; and a number `h` in the list for which adding all the numbers less than or equal to it is too much, `g` and `h` must be neighbour groups in the sorted list. If they were not, a number group between `g` and `h` would have been found by the search. (By "number group" I mean repeated elements.)

Comment: I'm not really following this algorithm from your description - in particular I don't see how it has a dependency on `k`. From my perspective, given that the numbers in the problem are real rather than integer, you can start by making a copy of the array with all of the numbers divided by k, and then solve it for k = 1, so the actual magnitude of k seems to be irrelevant.

Comment: @kaya3 how would you describe this idea's complexity?

Comment: @kaya3 I think I see what you mean -- would it depend on something idiosyncratic in the input related to how many divisions would lead to finding the right threshold?

Comment: I am not really sure I have understood your explanation of how the algorithm should work, but suppose you do an initial pass to find the minimum and maximum elements as your bounds for the binary search. Then you can test a candidate in O(n) time, so what matters is how many tests you have to make. It seems like you cannot easily bound that for a binary search, because e.g. what if the array is like `[1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 100]`? The correct value for the threshold will usually be 1, but the binary search candidate would never actually reach 1 exactly (except for floating-point imprecision).

Comment: I suppose when you are computing the sum of elements less than or equal to the candidate, you can also find the largest element less or equal than the candidate and the smallest element larger than the candidate, allowing you to narrow your bounds to only numbers that actually exist in the array, so e.g. you don't have to try 50 then 25 then 12.5 and so on because those aren't in the array anyway. In that case I'm not sure but it seems like a pathological input like `[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ..., 2^n]` could still result in O(n) passes being needed, for an O(n^2) complexity overall.

Comment: But as I said, I might be misunderstanding the algorithm anyway.

Comment: @kaya3 Thank you for your thoughtful comments! Could you please add to the pathological input example what K would need to be to result in O(n^2) complexity?

Comment: I think the example in my previous comment is only pathological if you initialise the upper bound as the maximum element in the array, in which case K = 1 would exhibit quadratic behaviour (as far as I can tell). But you could instead initialise the upper bound as the largest element <= K, and in that case the pathological example would have to be like `[2^n - 1, 2^n - 2, 2^n - 4, 2^n - 8, ...]`and K would be something like the sum of the whole array minus 1. Basically the idea is that with a geometric progression, testing the midrange only eliminates O(1) elements per pass.

Answer (score 0):

Use a max heap; call it H. I'll use sum(H) to refer to the sum of elements in H. Add elements to H if either of the following are true:

- sum(H) + elt <= k
- max(H) > elt (in which case we remove max(H) and add the elt in question).

Running time is O(n log |H|) <= O(n log k) since H only contains positive integers.

Space is |H| <= k.

At the end, H contains the max number of elements that sum to <= k, so |H| is your answer.